# What is the System objects in chrome javascript memory profiler

Tags: javascript, memory, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I'm profiling javascript application using Chrome dev tools.

I see that the only memory area that grows is System objects total.

I wonder how could I understand what causes such behavior as there are no details in the tool showing which system objects got leaked.

I've taken a look at app allocation, but it doesn't change much over time ...
When I'm using timeline feature heap grows over 500mb

[image: initial snapshot"]

[image: snapshot after multi-hour usage]

[image: snapshot after usage of timeline tool]

Comment: Parameter you are mentioning in your question of Heap Statistics is not "System Objects Total" . "System Objects" is different and "Total" is different.

Comment: The easiest way to find the cause for heap growth is to compare two snapshots in the comparison view. It could be DOM nodes that are still referenced by code although they are no longer part of the DOM tree.

Comment: Previously it was named [V8 heap](https://crbug.com/346335), technically [objects with "distance">=100000000](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/heap_snapshot_worker/JSHeapSnapshot.js?q=%22getStatistics%22+-file:test+-file:debug/&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=407). See [terminology](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-101?hl=en). I think, system heap may grow because of the debugger itself. Compare the mem usage without it in Chrome's Shift-Esc task manager or chrome://tracing/

Comment: You probably could have put that as an answer and it would have been satisfactory.

Comment: @SergeyDryganets Just a hunch, but if you're profiling stuff... that profile that builds over time just like the trend you're seeing has to be *stored somewhere.* Guess where it gets stored? I don't know. Could be there. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [JSHeapSnapshot.js](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/heap_snapshot_worker/JSHeapSnapshot.js?q=_calculateStatistics&sq=package:chromium&dr=C) implementation in Chromium, as mentioned in a comment by wOxxOm, a comparison for a given node distance to 100000000 is performed (`distances[ordinal] >= WebInspector.HeapSnapshotCommon.baseSystemDistance`, where `WebInspector.HeapSnapshotCommon.baseSystemDistance = 100000000`) and if passing, the size is accumulated into the System segment of the pie chart.

The [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/8dbfbc660f4d38a2c7f1926062c143a1a9e4c53e) that last modifies this value mentions,

> Currently if a user object is retained by both a system-space object
> (e.g. a debugger) and another user object, the system object might be
> shown earlier in the retainers tree. This happens if its distance is
> smaller than distances of other retaining user objects.

> The patch treats links from system-space objects to user objects with
> less priority, so these links are shown at the bottom of the retainers
> tree.

Which indicates that system-space objects on the javascript heap are utilized by debuggers and other internals to the browser (V8, WebKit, etc.). They are outside of the direct control of script allocated heap objects.

wOxxOm also mentioned that the name used to be V8 heap. That is, objects that V8 allocates that are out of reach of the executing script.

**It's highly likely that running profiling and taking snapshots performs allocations in that category of heap objects as well, causing the pattern you see of building system allocations over time.**