# NodeJS memory growth (memory leak)

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on my NodeJS app, and I can see the growth of memory consumption is about 100 kb per hour.
When I do profiling with --inspect node flag and analyse heap dumps in chrome-devtools

[image: what i see]

it shows that "code" section on "statistic" view is constantly growing:

[image: 1] 
[image: 2]

So, is it a memory leak, or is it ok for node?
The application is idling, I do not do any special actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the System objects in chrome javascript memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150569/what-is-the-system-objects-in-chrome-javascript-memory-profiler)

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection sometimes just recycle some complicated objects if it is necessary, so if xour memory is full and it needs space. So no, you don't have a memory leak if the memory is steadily growing, however you got one if it is increasing over gc cycles.