# Heap snapshots statistics explain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am comparing multiple snapshot using chrome devtools, could some one help explain details what is Code and System Objects under Statistics. By comparing multiple snapshots, the Code is keep increasing, what does that mean exactly? Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with this but maybe this link will help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150569/what-is-the-system-objects-in-chrome-javascript-memory-profiler