# NodeJS memory leak - what exactly is System Object and Typed Arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I've got an application that reads through a folder full of `.tar.gz` files, one at a time and writes processed data to disk. Everything operates on streams, and there shouldn't be more in-memory than a couple of hundred queued promises.

However, over a couple of hours, the memory taken grows from ~60mb to 2gb, and at this point, Node crashes.

I've created to heap snapshots of the application.

One created after a while of running, when Resident Set was about 80mb, as reported by `process.memoryUsage()`:

[image]

One after a much longer while, RSS equals ~120mb:

[image]

While it's nowhere the 2gb amount it accumulated over a night, we can  see `TypedArrays` (I think steram buffers count there?) and `System Objects` grew significantly.

First off, why is it so much smaller than the memory usage reported by system (~12mb vs ~150mb)?
Second, basing on that growth, we can extrapolate and assume that Typed Arrays and System objects grew further, and were one of the things that caused excessive memory usage over time.

Therefore, what exactly are Typed Arrays? How do they related to streams? And what are System Objects?

process.memoryUsage from a third session, slightly longer than the second one:

```
{
  "rss": 149794816,
  "heapTotal": 51036160,
  "heapUsed": 12103496,
  "external": 1531733,
  "arrayBuffers": 329913
}
```

Comment: If you haven't found these yet in searching, they might help with the basic knowledge you're asking about: [System objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737301) and [Typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)